# Finding accounts greater than specified transaction amount

Tags: sql-server

I have a bank db with  two tables `accountmaster` and `transactionmaster`.

`Accountmaster` has columns:

```
accid(pk)
accname
bal
branch
```

`Transactionmaster` columns:

```
Tnumber(pk)
dot
txnAmt
transactiontype
accid(fk)
branch(fk)
```

I want to find the below without using instead of triggers.

1. whenever a transaction is made by the accountholder (transaction type like deposit, withdraw) it should reflect in the balance of accountmaster table.
2. whenever an accountholder makes a transaction > 50000 (withdraw or deposit), that transaction details are to be inserted into a new table 'hightransaction' and remove that particular transaction in the transactionmaster table.

I tried something like this but in the result only column names are displayed and no values.

First I copied the transactionmaster into newtable hightransaction

```
select * 
into hightransaction 
from transactionmaster
where 1 = 2
```

then I created a trigger

```
create trigger [dbo].[transaction2]
on transactionmaster
for insert
as
    declare @transtype nvarchar(10);

    select @transtype = [TXNTYPE] 
    from inserted

    if (select txnamt from inserted) > 75000
    begin
        insert into [dbo].[hightransactionmaster3]
            select 
                dot, txntype, chqnum, chqdate, txnamt, 
                acid, brid, userid 
            from 
                inserted
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into [dbo].[TRANSACTIONMASTER] 
            select 
                 dot, txntype, chqnum, chqdate, txnamt, 
                 acid, brid, userid 
             from 
                 inserted
    end
```

and I tried to execute

```
select * from hightransaction
```

The output is only column names and no values.

Comment: I don't think you need to store the balance anywhere in the database, create a `View` on the `Transactionmaster` which calculates the balance on the fly when queried. For your second requirement , you need a stored procedure. If you do need to store the balance, then one stored procedure should be able to do all for you.

Comment: I don't know that the second one is possible without a trigger, unless you just mean modifying whatever procedure you currently have that inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a stored procedure like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[transaction]
@transactionAmt int 
/*
ADD OTHER PARAMETERS HERE
*/ 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

 IF (@transactionAmt > 50000)
  BEGIN
    /*INSERT STATEMENT FOR HIGHTRANSCTION TABLE*/
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
    /*INSERT STATEMENT FOR TRANSACTIONMASTER TABLE*/
  END
END
GO
```

This is provided that you have control over the application and can have it pass the parameters into a stored procedure.

Comment: Thq:) I now want to find that with triggers(without instead of)